# ある一定のダウンタイムがある並列システムを、特定の確率以上で常に必要並列数を上回らせるために必要な並列数は?

Tags: 数学

例えば web サービスは一般的にロードバランサーと並列数`N`で表されるワーカープロセスによって構築される場合が多いです。

今、あるワーカーが故障した時、そのワーカーが復帰するために必要な時間を`t`とします。ワーカーは、単位時間あたり`λ`の確率で故障し、その故障確率はそれまでの稼動時間に依らない、とします。
今、このサービスが問題なく稼動してワークロードをさばくためには、最低`m`個のワーカーがダウンしていない状態で稼動している必要があるとします。

このとき、確率論的に、ある一定の期間 `T` が与えられたとき、その期間の間のすべてのタイミングにおいて、上記の `m` 個のワーカーが稼動している確率 `p` が定義できると思い、これはこれまで出てきた `N`, `m`, `t`, `λ`, `T` についての関数になっていると思うのですが、その算出方法が分からずにいます。

## 質問

上記のような、ある並列システムが最低`m`の並列度を指定期間において達成している確率を求めたいのでが、これはどのようにすると求められますか?

これが分かることで、逆に算出された確率を信頼度とすることで、求められる信頼度に対して必要な `N` を求めたいと思い、質問しています。

Comment: 課題か何かでしょうか。実務的にはほとんど意味がない計算にしかならないと思います(構成要素の網羅度が足りなさすぎる、ある程度網羅したら複雑すぎて計算は困難)

Comment: > "N, m, t, λ, T についての関数になっていると思うのですが"

関数形を解析的に書けないように思います。 パラメータの値を具体的に与えたうえでシミュレーションして確率を求める方針をとることはできます。